# python 3 getting 401 using requests.put

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication

I am trying to put a file to a WebDav enabled URL.
The code looks like this:

```
headers = {'Authorization':'Basic', 'username': 'doc_iconx', 'password': 'doc_iconx'}
    id = "SOMEID"
    pw = "SOMEPW"
    try:
        url = 'https://mywebsite.com/Dir/'
        files = {'upload_file': open(fileName, 'rb')}
        r = requests.put(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(id,pw), files=files, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'
    })
```

I get back:

```
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

I know the ID/Password is good because I can do a put using curl

Any Ideas?

Comment: From what I see, you should probably use `HTTPBasicAuth` instead of `HTTPDigestAuth`. You also mention `post` but in your sample you are doing a `put`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo. I corrected the descriptions to be .put.

Comment: Tried using HTTPBasicAuth. Now I'm getting a : 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: https://content-qa.homedepot.com/IconX/Report/

Comment: If you want to upload a file, then you should use `post` as method.

Comment: Post won't work for our specific usage.  The website is using webdav and is expecting a PUT.

Comment: Ok, then you'll want to see why the API is returning 409: the app dev/manual should be able to tell. AFA the auth reply, I understand that was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your authentication scheme is using `Basic`, all you would have to do is to use `HTTPBasicAuth` instead of `HTTPDigestAuth`:

```
r = requests.put(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(id,pw), files=files, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```

for which `requests` actually has even a shortcut, by not specifying the mode:

```
r = requests.put(url,auth=(id,pw), files=files, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two different problems going on. Sal, corrected my Auth error. The second error was a stupid user error.  I need to append the filename I wanted uploaded to the end of the URL. The way it was constructed put was trying to create a file named Report. However Report is an existing directory, where I intended to write the file.

Comment: Glad it's all working. Please consider accepting my answer as it resolved your original posted issue.